# Need to pull customers & their various sales activities-- only if a specific activity type has ever occurred

Tags: sql, report, ssms

I'm using SSMS to create a 'Lead Follow-Up' report to monitor follow ups from Reps on sales leads.

Goal: Pull all customers w/ lead activity this yr & all activities AFTER the lead. (If multiple leads, then all activities after the 1st one.)

I'm able to pull all the customers with leads, BUT my code is pulling all activities (before & after the lead). I need it to just pull activities after the 'Lead' activity. If a customer has more than one 'Lead', then all the activities after the first 'Lead'.

Here are example tables & what I've tried:

Table 1: Customer (c)

| AcctID | CustomerName |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | Bob's Tires |
| 12 | Ned's Nails |
| 13 | Good Eats |
| 14 | Embers |

Table 2: Activities (a)

| AcctivityID | AcctID | Activity | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | Contact Added | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 11 | Lead | 2021-01-05 |
| 3 | 11 | Phone Call | 2021-01-06 |
| 4 | 12 | Marketing Email | 2021-02-01 |
| 5 | 12 | Lead | 2021-02-02 |
| 6 | 13 | Lead | 2021-02-03 |
| 7 | 13 | Phone Call | 2021-02-15 |
| 8 | 13 | Sales Email | 2021-02-15 |
| 9 | 14 | Cold Call | 2021-01-20 |

```
SELECT
c.CustomerName
, a.Activity
, a.Date
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Activities a ON c.AcctID = a.AcctID
WHERE
a.Date >= '2021-01-01'
AND c.AcctID IN (SELECT AcctID FROM Activities WHERE Activity LIKE 'Lead')
ORDER BY c.CustomerName, a.ContactDate
```

- Result needed:

| CustomerName | Activity | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob's Tires | Lead | 2021-01-05 |
| Bob's Tires | Phone Call | 2021-01-06 |
| Ned's Nails | Lead | 2021-02-02 |
| Good Eats | Lead | 2021-02-03 |
| Good Eats | Phone Call | 2021-02-15 |
| Good Eats | Sales Email | 2021-02-15 |

Comment: I'm a little confused on what your question is.  I think you may be asking more than one.  You should only ask one question at a time.

Comment: Okay, I'll remove Part 2 and post it separately. Thanks!  One sec...

Comment: Done -- Now I'm only asking one question  :)

Comment: Should the last two activities (Phone call and Sales email on `2021-01-15`) from `Good Eats` be included in your expected results since they occurred before the Lead date of `2021-02-03`?

Comment: You're right-- just updated the post. For Good Eats, Phone Call & Sales should have the dates 2021-02-15. Tks!

Comment: @LauraBullard Thanks for the confirmation. I've updated the demo db fiddle shared in the answer provided and this works with your updated sample data.  Let me know if the proposed answer works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach uses `MIN` as a window function and case expressions to filter based on `Lead` activities to determine the earliest lead activity for the year by that account (partitioned by AcctId). `is_valid_lead_item` is then created using a case expression that checks whether the current activity date is after the earliest lead date. The CTE `lead_activities` also filters based on your earliest considered data in the WHERE clause. Finally this is joined to your customers table to include customer details while also filtering to include only activities after the first lead activity for that year.

```sql
WITH lead_activities AS (
    SELECT 
        la.*,
        CASE
            WHEN la.Date >= MIN(CASE WHEN la.Activity='Lead' THEN la.Date END) OVER (PARTITION BY la.AcctId) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END as is_valid_lead_item
    FROM 
        Activities la
    WHERE 
        la.Date > '2021-01-01'
)
SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
    a.Activity,
    a.Date
FROM
    Customer c
INNER JOIN
    lead_activities a ON c.AcctID = a.AcctID AND
                         a.is_valid_lead_item=1
ORDER BY c.CustomerName, a.Date
```

[View demo on db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c64936f205d43d7d87a9901b1bda93ec)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Oh my goodness, YESSS!! Thank you so much, I've been messing with this for a seriously embarrassing amount of time! 

I'm kinda new to coding, so I also really appreciate your explanation of what everything in your script is doing. So helpful.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I'm sure you'll continue to grow on your coding journey, all the best!